# Wood fiber from pocket door

Tags: bathroom, doors, pocket-door

My son accidentally sprayed water from the shower onto the tile floor.  The water made its way to the pocket door area and it caused the door trim to swell, and the door became difficult to open and close.

This eventually went away, but a week or two later, the door became difficult to open and close.  Eventually some wood fiber started to get rolled out under the door.  Looking under the door, there was a bunch of loose fiber on the bottom of the door.  I scraped it off and it came back about a week later.

What is causing this?  Is there anything I can do short of opening up the wall and replacing the pocket door?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your pocket door was probably cut down to fit over the tile floor exposing the wood fiber/filler inside the door. The water soaked into the bottom and once it dried out, the material fell out. Before replacing the door, I'd wait to see if more material falls out. The material that was affected by the water might be gone or almost gone. Since the pocket door is supported by the top, there's no chance of the door falling out. For the time being, see what happens.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for helping me solve this.  I'll give it some time and see what happens